# Excluding specific user role from query

Tags: database, users

I have this query, which fetches all users with the role #7.

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(ur.uid) 
  FROM {users_roles} AS ur
  WHERE ur.rid IN (:rids)';

$result = db_query($query, array(':rids' => array(7)));
```

Some users currently have both roles #7 and #8. I beleive they are all fetched by this query. I would like to exclude users with the role #8.

Can someone help me?

Comment: this query is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(ur.uid) FROM `users_roles` AS ur 
WHERE ur.rid = (:rids) AND ur.uid 
NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM `users_roles` WHERE rid = (:rids2))';

$result = db_query($query, array(':rids' => 7, ':rids2' => 8));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(ur.uid) 
  FROM {users_roles} AS ur
  WHERE ur.rid IN (:rids) AND ur.rid NOT IN (:rids2)';

$result = db_query($query, array(':rids' => array(7), ':rids2' => array(8)));
```

Or if you wanted just the more specific version

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(ur.uid) 
  FROM {users_roles} AS ur
  WHERE ur.rid = (:rids) AND ur.rid != (:rids2)';

$result = db_query($query, array(':rids' => 7, ':rids2' => 8));
```

Comment: this looks logical to me, however I still get users tagged in both roles :(